# Asynchronous functions queue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How can i create Functions queue.
here is an example of what i need to do.

```
db.connect(); // connecting

db.create({ hello: 'World'}).save(function (success) {
  // Connected ? if so execute this callback immediatly
  // otherwise Queue this whole operation and execute the callback.
});

db.get({ hello: 'World' }, function () {
  // Again connected ? execute immediatly
  // otherwise Queue this whole operation and execute later.
});
```

the problem i'm having isn't about how to store and execute the callbacks,
that's easy, the problem is how can i record the operation ?

Sure i can do this

```
 db.connect(function () {
   // connected ! do stuff..
 })
```

but it leads to callback hell!

Here is my implementation.

```
 function Database () {}

 Database.prototype.connect = function () {
   // connect here and emit connected.
   var self = this;
   connect(function () {
     self.connected = true;
     self.executeQueue();
   });
 };

Database.prototype.create = function (doc) {
  var self = this;
  // what should i do here ?

  // maybe ?
  if (self.connected) {
    self._save(doc);
  } else {
    self.addToQueue(function () {
     self._save(doc);
    });
  }
};
```

The above implementation works, but the problem is the `if` statements that i will have to do
in every function, this is bad for me for many reasons (unit testing etc..).

Is there any other way that i can tackle this problem ?

Comment: I think you might be interested in [jQuery's Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). The idea is that you immediately return an object which will be resolved later. In jQuery, it is commonly used to chain AJAX handlers.